# How do I send custom HTTP header to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, http, header

I am using jQuery to send a custom header with every AJAX request.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader ("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ":" + sessionID));
    },
});
```

I want to be able to read the header on my Node.js application.

This is what I am doing:

```
http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    console.log(req.headers);
........
```

The output does my header like this:

```
  { host: 'localhost:9000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'access-control-request-method': 'GET'
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36',
  'access-control-request-headers': 'authorization',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9' }
```

I was expecting the see the values of my authorization header. What should I do to get it?

Comment: Perhaps because it's failing because it's a CORS request - CORS can mess with you :p - look for `withCredentials` in [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a cross-domain call, you need to set the withCredentials property to true on the XHR.

Check out the section xhrFields.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS EXAMPLE:

```
$.ajax({
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('user + ":" + sessionID'));
    },
    url: "YOUR URL NODEJS"
});
```